# python websocket listener javascript

Tags: python, websocket

```
import websocket
import thread
import time

def on_message(ws, message):
    print message

def on_error(ws, error):
    print error

def on_close(ws):
    print "### closed ###"

def on_open(ws):
    def run(*args):
        for i in range(3):
            time.sleep(1)
            ws.send("Hello %d" % i)
        time.sleep(1)
        ws.close()
        print "thread terminating..."
    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://echo.websocket.org/",
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()
```

How could I use this code to listen to 2 webscokcets simultaneously? for example `localhost:8888` and `localhost:8889`

And one more question, if I just want to listen to port do I need the `on_open` function or is enough to just declare it in main function?